# .NET regex not working client side

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

I am using the following regex in .NET to validate that a string contains 12 numeric characters and it works perfectly. (EG: 000000174064)

```
public static string TwelveDigitNumber = @"^\d{12}$";
```

However that same regular expression does not work client side using javascript.

EDIT: I am using jquery validate, and have added the following function for regular expresssions

```
// regex validation
$.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function (value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        },
        "Please check your input."
);


 rules: {
                    "Number": {
                        maxlength: 12, regex: "^\d{12}$"
                    },
```

Comment: `/^\d{12}$/.test("000000174064") //true` Seems to work fine

Comment: To clarify: what exactly does "does not work" mean? Do you have a javascript error or does it always just fail?  Next, have you tested to ensure the values you expect are actually being sent in the parameters to your function?

Comment: The \ is used as escape character in JavaScript. Therefore it needs to be escaped by doubling it. So either `"^\\d{12}$"` or `/^\d{12}$/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result from `new RegExp( "^\d{12}$" )` is `/^d{12}$/` instead of `/^\d{12}$/` because of the escape backslash. It works in .NET because you have @ which I think skips the escaping.

Anyway, for static regexes you can just use regex literals:

`regex: /^\d{12}$/`

is same as

`regex: new RegExp( "^\\d{12}$" )`

You can then pass it directly to the function and it doesn't have to instantiate it every time.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation of what was happening.

Comment: @RyanSampson I also forgot to mention that javascript doesn't have equivalent for `@`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you typed the Regex like this:

```
var rgx = /^\d{12}$/;

// or

var rgx = new RegExp('^\\d{12}$');

// or without the new keyword?
```

Comment: within the RegExp object you need to use `\\d` in place of `\d`